# $\lim_{x \to \infty} (x - \ln x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

When applying L'Hospital's Rule to

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (x - \ln x)$$

I would have thought the answer to be

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{x} \right) = 1$$

But the answers I am seeing are shown as

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} x \left(1 - \frac{\ln x}{x} \right) &= \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{x^2 - x \ln x}{x} \right) \\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{2x - 1 - \ln x}{1} \right) \\
&= \infty
\end{align}

Any advice on why my approach might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule applies specifically to a fraction where both numerator and denominator both approach zero, or both approach infinity.

Comment: OK thanks, what about indeterminite forms for $\infty - \infty$ such as here? Do they need to be rearranged to fractions so L'Hopsital's rule may apply?

Comment: Yes. You can't just differentiate it and get the correct answer, you have to get it to the correct fraction form of $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

You can’t apply l’Hopital to the original limit which is in the form $\infty-\infty$, use that

$$x-\ln x=x\left(1-\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)$$

and apply l’Hopital to $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}$$

which is in the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: It's a good hint, and correct that l'Hôpital's rule does not apply to the original form.  I might have been a little more forceful in saying why, but others may wish to beat that drum in their Answers.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for the appreciation of course we could discuss that more but the best thing is refer to the orginal theorem to check under which conditions it works.

Answer (score 2):

If the L'Hopital formalism $\lim_{x\to c}{f(x)\over g(x)}=\lim_{x\to c}{f'(x)\over g'(x)}$ when ${f(x)\over g(x)}\to{\infty\over\infty}$ generalized to $\lim_{x\to c}(f(x)-g(x))=\lim_{x\to c}(f'(x)-g'(x))$ when $f(x)-g(x)\to\infty-\infty$, just because ${\infty\over\infty}$ and $\infty-\infty$ are both indeterminate, we would have obvious nonsense like

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(3x-2x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(3-2)=1$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $x- \ln x = \ln(e^x) + \ln(x^{-1}) = \ln (\frac{e^x}{x}).$

Comment: That's also a nice way!